# TransactionProxyFactoryBean when switching from configuration-based Service beans to annotation based service beans

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, proxy, transactions

I read about using

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="tld.mydomain.business">
      <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service"/>
  </context:component-scan>
```

and annotate my service beans with @Service("myService"), and thought great, I'll do that, since I'm already doing that with my controllers. My usual service bean configuration looks like

```
  <bean id="userService" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
      <bean class="tld.mydomain.business.UserServiceImpl"/>
    </property>
    <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="tld.mydomain.business.UserService"/>
  </bean>
```

so now that I generate them, how do I wrap them in a Hibernate proxy such as TransactionProxyFactoryBean? Or is there a better way to do that as well?

I have not yet gone all the way and used @Repository as well, is that required?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **TransactionProxyFactoryBean** is not encouraged in modern Spring applications, although it still works. The typical approach nowadays is to annotate classes with **@Transactional**, and then stick this element in your application context file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

This and other strategies are [discussed](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) in great depth in the reference document, and there's even a side note about **TransactionProxyFactoryBean**.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I had followed a book on Spring 2 that recommended the TransactionProxyFactoryBean, I see now I should have checked out the documentation more carefully. Just a quick follow-up, though: this seems to be only for the scenario where there is only a single transaction manager. I, unfortunately, have two as I need to work with two different databases. This was no problem using TransactionProxyFactoryBean. Table 9.2 and 9.3 don't seem to suggest I can

Comment: Hmm, when I do that, I get the following exception when accessing my services: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0' must be of type [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice], but was actually of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]

Comment: Could it be that the @Service("myService") and @Transactional annotations clash?

Comment: After having spent hours on this bug I decided it was better to post the question as a separate question than a follow-up in this thread. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636063/transactional-services-beannotofrequiredtypeexception-should-be-advice-but-i

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for

`<context:include-filter type="annotation"expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service"/>`

Spring will register `@Service, @Repository, @Component...` once they are found in the base package.

Like @Rob said either use `@Transactional` or `<aop:config>...</aop:config>` to handle your transactions at the service level.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've removed the extra clutter. Do you have any suggestions to why I get the BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException above creeps in? Or how to deal with more than one transaction manager? I see from the doc that I can give different advice using <aop:config/> but it seems to me that that is still within only one transaction manager?

Comment: Usually `BeanNotOfRequiredType` when you are injecting a bean of the wrong type but I can't speak further unless you post the stacktrace. Well you only need 1 `PlatformTransactionManager`, there's no need for 2 unless you have 2 diff `DataSource`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different resources that need to be in the same transaction, then you will need to use JTA. See my answer to an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75700/jpa-multiple-transaction-managers/78479#78479). Your config would need to look something like:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<bean id="txManager" 
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="appserver/jndi/path" />
</bean>
```

Where `appserver/jndi/path` would need to be replaced with the JNDI path of the JTA transaction manager that comes with your application server (although you can use a standalone JTA transaction manager such as JOTM as well). Typical paths as mentioned in the [2.5.x API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) are:

- "java:comp/UserTransaction" for Resin 2.x, Oracle OC4J (Orion), JOnAS (JOTM), BEA WebLogic
- "java:comp/TransactionManager" for Resin 3.x
- "java:appserver/TransactionManager" for GlassFish
- "java:pm/TransactionManager" for Borland Enterprise Server and Sun Application Server (Sun ONE 7 and later)
- "java:/TransactionManager" for JBoss Application Server

Comment: Hi Toolkit, thanks a lot for your input. I've been able to get around it when I used TransactionProxyFactoryBean in that it's not strictly necessary to keep them in the same transaction, I can also have two, one of them is read-only. That's why I asked about saying what transaction goes where. Combining them both into one seems like the best idea. But both are JDBC connections, I haven't been using JNDI. But I'll read up on your suggestion in the morning (it's midnight over here now)    Cheers -Nik