# Transactional services => BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException, should be Advice, but is TransactionInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, transactions, service, annotations

After following the great advice given in [a thread about service beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632256/transactionproxyfactorybean-when-switching-from-configuration-based-service-beans/1634049) I have made a Service that is listed under. I've tried putting @Transactional at the interface level, interface method level, class level and class method level. However I do it, I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0' must be of type [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice], but was actually of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]
```

UPDATE: I only get this error when I've defined `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager/>` but I without it, the @Transactional annotation doesn't do anything and I'm left without a Hibernate session.

Any idea why I get this error? I'm fairly new to this, but it looks like I'm doing what the PetClinic example is doing, and I've googled around for hours and browsed the docs without getting any wiser.

UPDATE: I've also found a way to config myself into the same error trying to follow suggestions from [Abhi On Java](http://java-x.blogspot.com/2008/04/integrating-spring-and-hibernate_17.html). I've added that all the way in the bottom of this post.

My config, interface and class is listed below. This is the config that loads the services (UPDATE: What loads the services is in the bottom. The first part is concerning my database and more):

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"   value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"     value="jdbc:mysql://${db.host}:{db.port}/{db.name}" />
    <property name="username" value="{db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="{db.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="{db.minConnections}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="{db.maxConnections}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
      <list>
       <value>tld.mydomain.data.entities.User</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

  <bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="flushMode" value="0" />
  </bean> 

<!--

  <bean id="txProxyTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
      <props>
        <prop key="create*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
-->
  <context:component-scan base-package="tld.mydomain.business"/>
```

This is the interface:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import tld.mydomain.data.entities.User;
import tld.mydomain.data.entities.keys.UserId;

public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService, CRUDService<User, UserId> {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User lookupUser(String username);

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User publicAliasForUser(String username);
}
```

and class:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import tld.mydomain.commons.RandomString;
import tld.mydomain.data.entities.User;

@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl extends AbstractCRUDServiceImpl<User, String> implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private LogService logService;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public User lookupUser(String username) {

        if(username == null || username.equals("") || username.equals("anonymousUser"))
            return null;

        try {
          List<User> matchingUsers = (List<User>) DAO.getSession().createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("username", username)).list();
          int n = matchingUsers.size();
          if(n == 0) return null;
          if(n > 1) logService.logWarning("Got " + n + " users back, expected just one. Data inconsistency, multiple users with username = " + username);
          return matchingUsers.get(0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          logService.logException(ex);
          return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        if(username == null || username.equals("") || username.equals("anonymousUser"))
            return null;

        User user = this.lookupUser(username);
        if(user == null) {
            logService.logWarning("Couldn't find a user to match, throw out a garbage object");
            user = new User();
            user.setUsername(RandomString.getString(30));
            user.setPassword(RandomString.getString(30));
        }

        return user.getUserDetails();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public User publicAliasForUser(String alias) {
        List<User> publicUsers = DAO.getSession().createCriteria(User.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("alias", alias))
        .list();

        if(publicUsers.size() <= 0) return null;
        if(publicUsers.size() > 1) logService.logWarning("Data inconsistency: More than one alias for a user with alias " + alias);
        return publicUsers.get(0);
    }

}
```

This is the full exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0' must be of type [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice], but was actually of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.getAdvice(AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.getInterceptors(DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.java:78)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(AdvisedSupport.java:481)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:188)
    at $Proxy28.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Finally, as promised, here is what I can add of configuration to get the exact same exception:

```
 <aop:config>
  <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethods" expression="execution(* tld.mydomain.business..*(..))" />
  <aop:advisor  advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethods" />
 </aop:config>

 <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager" >
  <tx:attributes>
   <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
  </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>
```

This again gives me the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'txAdvice' must be of type [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice], but was actually of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.getAdvice(AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJProxyUtils.isAspectJAdvice(AspectJProxyUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJProxyUtils.makeAdvisorChainAspectJCapableIfNecessary(AspectJProxyUtils.java:49)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.extendAdvisors(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    ... 26 more
```

Cheers

Nik

Comment: You have a abstract "txProxyTemplate" bean definition, but no child definitions for it, so you're never going to have any tx proxies. Are you sure this is the way you have it?

Comment: Yup, I noticed that and commented it out. It's a leftover from when I used to make beans like '<bean id="userService" parent="txProxyTemplate">'. But removing it doesn't seem to change anything, I get the exact same exception in the exact same way

Comment: There's nothing in the configuration you have posted that will cause your exception. Something else must be at work here, something you haven't mentioned. Try replacing the `context:component-scan` with explicit bean definitions, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. It worked great when I had my service beans explicitly defined, it's now that I'm using annotation based scanning that they fail. But then I had them all as a parent of txProxyTemplate. Is your suggestion to go back to that, or is there another way I can explicitly define them while still keep using @Transactional and @Autowired annotations?

Comment: Seems I'm mistanken and confused... <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> seems to be the one "causing" the exception, and it happens regardless of whether I use <context:component-scan base-package="dk.danskscanning.business"/> or define the service as <bean id=".." class=".."/>

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect early that it happens when using annotation-drive transaction-manager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I see the problem now:

> ... must be of type
>   [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice], but was
>   actually of type
>   [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]

Given that `TransactionInterceptor` is an implementation of `org.aopalliance.aop.Advice`, this suggests to me that you have a classloading issue. Specifically, you either have two copies of Spring being loaded by two different classloaders, or two copies of aop-alliance being loaded by two different classloaders. In this situation, you can get `instanceof` errors or `ClassCastExceptions` that can be a bit hard to diagnose.

I suggests looking through your manifests and classpaths, including  the app-server's own classpaths, and make sure your application can only find Spring and aop-alliance in one place. Remember that the Spring JARs already include a copy of the aop-alliance stuff, so you don't need another copy.

Comment: Thanks Skaffman, I'm in the process of going through my JARs and find that there are, indeed, a few double-ups, including aopalliance*.jar. I'll rummage through them all and take out what I can, re-test and get back to you. It may not be until tomorrow, but I have a good feeling about this :-) Thanks for all your help so far! :-)